# Automatically scroll detailsview alongside chosen gridview row

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, gridview, detailsview

I have an ASP.NET gridview that has a couple of associated detailsviews and a secondary gridview.  When a user clicks on a row in the gridview, the detailsviews pop up on the right side of the gridview.  This is fine, but as the number of gridview rows has grown, the detailsviews get pushed lower and lower on the page making them difficult and frustrating for users to locate.

What I want to do is when the user selects a row they're interested in, align the top of the detailsview with the chosen row.

I've tried setting the CSS with:

```
[id$="ContentPlaceHolder1_dvProductionReport"], 
[id$="ContentPlaceHolder1_dvOraclePartDetails"], 
[id$="ContentPlaceHolder1_gvReceipts"] 
{
    position: fixed;
}
```

This didn't work.  I've also tried to position it (in this example using only the first selector) with JavaScript using [this example](http://www.wduffy.co.uk/blog/keep-element-in-view-while-scrolling-using-jquery/):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function () {
        //var $scrollingDiv = [id$ = "ContentPlaceHolder1_dvProductionReport"];
        var elements = document.querySelector('[id$="ContentPlaceHolder1_dvProductionReport"]');
        console.log(elements);

        $(window).scroll(function () {
            elements
                .stop()
                .animate({ "marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop() + 30) + "px" }, "slow");
        });
    });
</script>
```

But this didn't work in Chrome since apparently "animate" is a keyword in Chrome, but the [example](http://www.wduffy.co.uk/blog/wp-content/demos/jquery-scrolling-element/) works in Firefox.

**The Question:**

How can I keep a detailsview in view while the user scrolls, or at least pop up the details view aligned with the row in the gridview they've chosen?

**Edit:**
In response to @rexroxm 's suggestion:
I've added: 
`<div style="position: absolute"><td>...</td></div>` around the first detailsview.  This has made no difference, so I've added this to the .CSS file:

```
[id$="ContentPlaceHolder1_dvProductionReport"], 
[id$="ContentPlaceHolder1_dvOraclePartDetails"], 
[id$="ContentPlaceHolder1_gvReceipts"] 
{
    position: absolute;
}
```

I can see that the CSS for `position: absolute;` is showing up on all three of the dependent detailsviews (2) and gridview (1).  If I check the style in Chrome > Inspect > Developer tools, I see `position: absolute;` shows up for all three, in the first view, but it's lined through in the second view (not sure what these are called, but they show you the CSS styles for the element you've chosen).  I've also tried using:

```
[id$="ContentPlaceHolder1_dvProductionReport"], 
[id$="ContentPlaceHolder1_dvOraclePartDetails"], 
[id$="ContentPlaceHolder1_gvReceipts"] 
{
    position: absolute !important;
}
```

Which also shows up as lined through.

Here is the entire `<td>...</td>`, sorry it's long, but it might be helpful:

```
        <td>
        <div style="position: absolute">
            <asp:DetailsView ID="dvProductionReport" runat="server" Height="50px" 
            Width="125px"
            EnableModelValidation="True" AutoGenerateRows="False" 
            DataKeyNames="PartNumber" Caption="Part Details" >
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#66FF66" ForeColor="Black" />
            <Fields>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="PartNumber" HeaderText="Part Number:" 
                    SortExpression="PartNumber" >
                <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" 
                    Wrap="False" />
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="False" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="AssemblyPartNumber" 
                    HeaderText="Assembly Part Number:" SortExpression="AssemblyPartNumber" >
                <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" 
                    Wrap="False" />
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="False" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Line Down:" SortExpression="LineDown">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("LineDown")) %>' />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("LineDown")) %>' />
                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("LineDown")) %>' 
                            Enabled="false" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="False" />
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="False" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Product" HeaderText="Product:" 
                    SortExpression="Product" >
                    <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="False" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="False" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Assembly" HeaderText="Assembly:" 
                    SortExpression="Assembly" >
                    <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="False" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="False" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderNumber" HeaderText="Order Number:" 
                    SortExpression="OrderNumber" >
                    <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="False" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="False" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Department" HeaderText="Department:" 
                    SortExpression="Department" >
                    <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="False" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="False" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DateAdded" HeaderText="Date Added:" 
                    SortExpression="DateAdded" DataFormatString="{0:d}" >
                    <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="False" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="False" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DateRequired" HeaderText="Date Required:" 
                    SortExpression="DateRequired" DataFormatString="{0:d}" >
                    <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="False" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="False" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="QuantityRequired" HeaderText="Quantity Required:" 
                    SortExpression="QuantityRequired" >
                    <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="False" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="False" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Filled:" SortExpression="Filled">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Filled")) %>' />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Filled")) %>' />
                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Filled")) %>' 
                            Enabled="false" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="False" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="False" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Closed:" SortExpression="Closed">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Closed")) %>' />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Closed")) %>' />
                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Closed")) %>' 
                            Enabled="false" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="False" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="False" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductionCell" HeaderText="Production Cell:" 
                    SortExpression="ProductionCell" >
                    <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="False" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="False" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductionReason" HeaderText="Production Reason:" 
                    SortExpression="ProductionReason" >
                    <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="False" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="True" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductionComments" 
                    HeaderText="Production Comments:" SortExpression="ProductionComments" >
                    <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="False" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="True" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ReportingAssociate" 
                    HeaderText="Reporting Associate:" SortExpression="ReportingAssociate" >
                    <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="False" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="False" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="EmailAddress" HeaderText="Email Address:" 
                    SortExpression="EmailAddress" >
                    <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="False" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="False" />
                </asp:HyperLinkField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="RootCause" HeaderText="Root Cause:" 
                    SortExpression="RootCause" >
                    <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="False" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="False" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="BuyerComments" HeaderText="Buyer Comments:" 
                    SortExpression="BuyerComments" >
                    <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="False" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="True" />
                </asp:BoundField>
            </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
        </div>
    </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep detailsview's `position:absolute` that way it will stay on your page/view. When someone clicks on a user in primary gridview you probably bind it's data to the secondary gridview and then show it. Setting it `position` to `absolute` in `style` of the container `div/table`  will keep it in the view. You may also put a cross button on the upper right side of the div containing the secondary Gridview which sets `display:none` with the event `onclick`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I haven't been able to get this to work, please take a look at my edited question with what I've tried.